# Get textbox word on mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox/textarea and I want get only one word with mouse pointed. then display that word in a another text box.
Ex: When I over my mouse pointer on one word, it should display in another textbox/textarea (only that word).

I saw many posts with  tag, but it is not possible to add in textbox/textarea
Also I need to create function with mouse click,

I need mouse hover function and mouse click function both ways to get word.

```
See the
```

[Demo and update this](http://jsfiddle.net/3eAxT/)

Comment: Can you show what all have you tried?

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3eAxT/1/

Comment: This might not be trivial in a `textarea`. If I were doing this in the text portion of some other HTML container, I might be tempted to wrap all the words in a `span` to solve this.

Comment: Yeah I tried to make DIV editable and it works fine, but when I break lines, it will automatically remove line breaks. any idea?
see [this](http://jsbin.com/enuqov/31/)

Comment: Abhishek Prakash >> see my previous comment example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will be possible with a plain textarea, but here's a way you could do it using a div with 'contenteditable' enabled.

Works quite nicely, **[see my jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/4FVX6/1/)** 
(note: click outside of the editable area to re-enable highlighting after any edits).

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
    <div>
        Content here.
    </div>
    <div>
        More content here.
    </div>
</div>
Current word: <span id="word"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
var wrapwords = function() {
    $('#editor > div').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
    });

    $('#editor span').hover(
        function() { $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); },
        function() { $('#word').text(''); $(this).css('background-color',''); }
    );
};

$('#editor').on('focus', function() {
    $('#editor span').contents().unwrap();
});

$('#editor').on('blur', function() {
    wrapwords();
});

wrapwords();
```

Comment: This is wrong..Please try to add some text with line breaks. It is the same I have done in my previous comment.<b> [See this my previous](http://jsbin.com/enuqov/31)</b>

Comment: Great Job!
If you can make this same thing with the textarea or text box, it will great favor for me.